# how to access elements inside an included view in a android xml layout file?

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a layout and I included an android layout inside it :

```
<include
    layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice" />
```

Once my whole view is inflated how can I access the element inside the `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` ? I guess there are a TextView and a CheckBox that I should be able to use but what's their id ?

EDIT:
Do I need to inflate more than one thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it doing this:

```
CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Comment: It's very strange because android.R.id contains all of the publicly available ids that the Android OS uses to reference various default items. Every Android application should have access to this.

Answer (score 2):

I complete such tasks by providing an `@+id` to the `<include/>` statement. So for something like your example above I would write...

```
  <include
  android:id="@+id/listItemMultiChoiceWrapper"
  layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice" />
```

You could then access the *text1* field by writing at your activity/fragment level (where ever you set the view containing the `<include/>`)

```
  final CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(id.listItemMultiChoiceWrapper).findViewById(id.text1);
```

If that doesn't work then check for duplicate ids confusing the situation (Lint should pick these up too).

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for simple_list_item_multiple_choice from Android SDK:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
/>
```

I guess you can handle it from here.